# Login Authentication for custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-custom-user

I have custom user model. I am able to signup but when it comes to login and logout, i have no idea what is happening. Login Form is not logging in the user when I submit the form, it just says the user with that username already exists (it is kind of acting like signup page)
How to resolve this issue

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
# Create your models here.

class Organisation(models.Model):
    organisation_name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    contact_no = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta():
        unique_together = ['organisation_name','email']

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.organisation_name

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, organisation, email, password):
        if not organisation:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an organisation")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, organisation=organisation)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

#forms.py

```
from . import models
from django import forms
class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = models.MyUser
        fields = ('username','email','password','organisation')

class MyUserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=models.MyUser
        fields=("username","email","password","organisation")

        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():
                username=self.cleaned_data('username')
                email=self.cleaned_data('email')
                password=self.cleaned_data('password')
                organisation=self.cleaned_data('organisation')

                if not authenticate(username=username,email=email,password=password,organisation=organisation):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LOGIN")
```

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from . import models
from . import forms

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
# Create your views here.

class indexPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/inner_index.html'

class Create_Organisation(CreateView):
    model = models.Organisation
    fields = ('__all__')
    template_name  = 'accounts/organisation_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:inner_index")

class Create_Accounts(CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = models.MyUser
    form_class = forms.MyUserForm
    template_name = 'accounts/create_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:inner_index")

def  login_my_user(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=forms.MyUserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password=request.POST["password"]
            email=request.POST["email"]
            organisation = request.POST["organisation"]
            user=authenticate(username=username,email=email,password=password,organisation=organisation)
            if user:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect("home")

    else:
        form=forms.MyUserLoginForm()

    return render(request,"accounts/login_account.html",{'form':form})
```

#urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.indexPage.as_view(),name  = 'inner_index'),
    path('create_organisation/',views.Create_Organisation.as_view(),name='create_organisation'),
    path('create_account/',views.Create_Accounts.as_view(),name='create_account'),
    path('login_account/',views.login_my_user,name = 'login'),
]
```

#login_account.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block body_block %}
<form class="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

#setting.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/'
```